# Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns [Different Dup]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out why SQL is throwing this error when I've checked that number of variables match correctly. Does it have to do with the IF statement?

```
DECLARE 
    @ServerName VARCHAR(30),
    @SiteCode VARCHAR(4);

DECLARE SiteList CURSOR FAST_FORWARD
FOR SELECT 
        Cinema_strServerName, 
        Cinema_strCode 
    FROM 
        tblCinema;

OPEN SiteList;

FETCH NEXT FROM SiteList INTO 
    @ServerName, 
    @SiteCode;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

 -- Add Server Names To Exclude
 IF @ServerName IN ('test')
    BEGIN

        PRINT 'COPY \\' + @ServerName + 


    END


FETCH NEXT FROM SiteList INTO @ServerName
END

CLOSE SiteList
DEALLOCATE SiteList
```

**Error**:

> Cursorfetch: The number of variables declared in the INTO list must match that of selected columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second fetch (at the end of the loop) you still have one variable:

```
FETCH NEXT FROM SiteList INTO @ServerName
END

CLOSE SiteList
DEALLOCATE SiteList
```

To avoid errors like this one I usually use a diffrent pattern for cursors:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/252602/sql-server-cursors-missing-afterthought-safeguard-against-infinite-looping/252616#252616